# Is there a theory for estimating "node differences" using "edge samples" over graph

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, estimation, graph-theory

Assume a system consisting of several components. Each component is characterized by some real number.
A sample of a pair of components in the system, is a random variable normally distributed around the **difference** between the components (with known variance).

Given a set of samples (there may be more than one sample of the same pair), I am interested in estimating the differences between the pairs (it can be assumed that the collection of samples forms a connected graph).
Furthermore I'm interested in calculating the variance of the estimator.

Is there a theory that covers the issue?

Comment: It sounds like you could use standard estimation methods (e.g. maximum likelihood) for this problem. It is not entirely clear however what you mean by "differences between pairs", it might help to formulate this more precisely

Comment: Example. 3 nodes: v1=10, v2=20, v3=30. samples for v2-v1: would be {11.0, 9.5, 10.2}, samples for v3-v1 would be {21.6, 20.4}, samples for v3-v2 would be {10.4, 9.6}. I want to estimate the real values v2-v1, v3-v1, v3-v2 (= 10, 20, 10)

Comment: So you have $x_{ij} \sim \mathcal N(v_i-v_j,\sigma^2)$. Differentiating the log-likelihood with respect to the $v_i$'s will give you a linear system which you can easily solve for the MLE's, and the second derivatives can give you the estimator's covariance.

Comment: Differentiating the log-likelihood with respect to the vi's is what I did. Didn't understand the second part. I'm looking for a theoretical value that can be calculated from the original sigma's and is not depending on a specific samples...

Comment: In your case since the log-likelihood is quadratic in $v_i$, the second derivatives in fact do not depend on the data (i.e. the observed and expected Fisher Information matrices are the same). More generally there are  actually [theoretical arguments](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/65/3/457/233667?redirectedFrom=fulltext&login=false) in favor of using  the observed Fisher information   for estimating accuracy of MLE's.

Comment: There's a problem with this method. back to the 3-nodes example, if we ignore the v3-v1 samples and stay only with v2-v1 and v3-v2 samples, there's still something we can say about the value v3-v1, but the second derivative by v3 and v1 is 0...

Comment: It is not zero since you have terms involving $v_1$ and $v_3$

Comment: I can't see that. Assume two samples $x_1^{12},x_2^{12}$ for $v_2-v_1$ and two samples $x_1^{23},x_2^{23}$ for $v_3-v_2$. The log-likelihood in this case will be:
$$ l(v_1,v_2,v_3;x_1^{12},x_2^{12},x_1^{23},x_2^{23}) = [(x_1^{12}-v_2+v_1)^2+(x_2^{12}-v_2+v_1)^2]]/2\sigma_{12}^2+[(x_1^{23}-v_3+v_2)^2+(x_2^{23}-v_3+v_2)^2]/2\sigma_{23}^2$$
Differentiating by $v_1$ gives:
$$\partial l/\partial v_1 = [(x_1^{12}-v_2+v_1)+(x_2^{12}-v_2+v_1)]/\sigma_{12}^2$$
And then:
$$\partial^2 l/\partial v_1\partial v_3 = 0$$

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the example in your comment, you have

$$\partial^2 l/\partial v_i \partial v_j = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1/\sigma_{12}^2 & 1/\sigma_{12}^2 & 0 \\
1/\sigma_{12}^2 & 1/\sigma_{12}^2+1/\sigma_{23}^2 & 1/\sigma_{23}^2 \\
0 & 1/\sigma_{23}^2 & 1/\sigma_{23}^2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Normally you would have to invert this matrix to get the covariance of the $v_i$'s, however in this case the matrix is singular (you can verify that the determinant is zero), meaning that the data does not fully determine all of the unknown parameters.

You can see this by using the alternative parametrization: $\delta_1 = v_1-v_2, \delta_2 = v_2-v_3, \delta_3 = v_3$ (notice that it is invertible, i.e. you can  go back to the $v_i$'s from the $\delta_i$'s). This gives simply:

$$\partial^2 l/\partial \delta_i \partial \delta_j = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1/\sigma_{12}^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/\sigma_{23}^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

which has the "inverse"

$$[\partial^2 l/\partial \delta_i \partial \delta_j]^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\sigma_{12}^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_{23}^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \infty\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now if you want the variance of $v_1 - v_3 = \delta_1 + \delta_2$:

$$Var[\delta_1 + \delta_2] = Var[\delta_1] + Var[\delta_2] + 2Cov[\delta_1,\delta_2] = \sigma^2_{12} + \sigma^2_{23}.$$

More generally, if the Fisher information is singular, then there are some linear combinations of the parameters that are not determined by the data. You can remove them by reparametrizing using only the non-zero eigenvectors of the Fisher information, similarly to this simple example.